# RDFRefine - can't access imported ontology?

Tags: ontology, vocabulary, openrefine

I'm using OpenRefine and its extension RDFRefine. I'm trying to import an ontology which has its URI at http://purl.org/vocab/participation/schema# and suggested prefix: participation. When I add prefix and insert the URI, it gives me no problem. However, when i try to access its properties it says: 'Not in the imported vocabulary definition.' But I can still see it(participation) within Available prefixes.

Any idea why this is happening? Didn't face this issue when I imported the W3 Basic Geo vocabulary(https://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/).

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing that vocab URI. In this particular case the URI points to a webpage and does not seem to contain a formal definition of the ontology (in RDF) which might be what RDF Refine is looking for.

The page has a link to the RDF version: http://vocab.org/participation/schema-20080925.rdf

Maybe this can be solved by using this URI when loading the ontology?

Comment: I tried that too, but it gives me the same error. :/